# I need some help about plsql functions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to select sum of the salary where employee_id is less than 200. And here is my code.

```
declare 
  emp_id number;
  x number;
  function sum_max_salary (emp_id in number)    
    return number 
  is 
    v_result number;
  begin 
    select sum(salary) into v_result from employees 
     where employee_id<200;
    return v_result;
  end;
begin
  emp_id:=200;
  x:=sum_max_salary(emp_id);
  dbms_output.put_line(sum_max_salary);
end;
```

The above procedure gives me an error:

> ORA-06550: line 16, column 22: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SUM_MAX_SALARY'
>
> ORA-06550: line 16, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored 06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s" *Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. *Action: –

and I need help to find the issue.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to ask anything - please edit your question to ask a question. Do you get an error? Does it not work in the way you want it to? Something else?

Comment: Your output is trying to output the function call (`sum_max_summary`), not the result (`x`). You also don't use `emp_id` anywhere in the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just do the SQL:

```
select sum(salary) 
from employees 
where employee_id<200;
```

If you want to do it with PL/SQL

```
set servoutput on
declare 
emp_id number;
x number;
function sum_max_salary (emp_id in number)


return number 
is 
v_result number;
begin 
select sum(salary) into v_result from employees 
where employee_id<emp_id;
return v_result;
end;
begin
emp_id:=200;
x:=sum_max_salary(emp_id);
dbms_output.put_line(x);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on line

```
dbms_output.put_line(sum_max_salary);
```

you probably want to do

```
dbms_output.put_line(x);
```

`x`  ist the result of your function